# Unity: How do I make two different objects with Fixed Joints collide?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently making a VR game where the user can pick up object with both hands.
In order to realistically grab an object, I am using Fixed Joints to connect them to the hand.

**The Problem**

The problem is that when holding an object in each hand, they will not collide with each other. The objects when grabbed will interact with every other collider except each other.

And just to be clear, these objects have two separate Fixed Joint components that get connected to an object on the respective hand when grabbed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you tick `Enable Collisions` on the `FixedJoint` components?

Comment: @derHugo I just tried and that did not work. I believe`Enable Collisions` is for the two object connected by the same `FixedJoint` right?